# iPhone iAd Enabled App Published Still Showing Test Ads

Tags: iphone, iad

I integrated iAd in my application which got approved by Apple. I downloaded the app (FREE) to my device and ran it. For some reason instead of displaying real world ads it still says "Test Ads". Anyone experience this issue? The app got approved yesterday maybe it is too early to get the ads but I think Apple should not show test ads.

Comment: Have you enabled iAd in the ItunesConnect site?

Comment: Yes it is iAd enabled! Other people are getting the ads but I am still getting test ads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like Apple will always display TEST ads on the machine it was tested on.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, make sure you delete the binary you used in testing off of your phone, and off of iTunes if you distributed that way. The phone will see that the version numbers are the same, and skip some of the code upgrades. Once you reinstall from iTunes, you should be good to go! Congrats on getting the app out into the store.

Comment: I selected a distribution profile and then sent the app through the build and archive method. Also, the app is different version 1.2.